# proving Power Set Difference $P(A-B) \neq P(A)-P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I Have to prove that $P(A-B) \neq P(A)-P(B).$
I Know how to prove that $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cap P(B).$,but not this one.
Can someone help me please?Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched for a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, I didnt find example for $P(A−B)= P(A)−P(B)$.

Comment: To disprove an equality you only need find an example where equality fails, not an example where the equality is satisfied. I see that several people have immediately jumped in to provide an answer which you could easily have found by yourself if you had been given a few seconds to do so.

Comment: But,If there are cases that $P(A−B)=P(A)−P(B)$ and i didnt find that.
Is the eqation is still unequal ?
Thanks.

Comment: One can interpret your question in one of two ways. First, that the two expressions are never equal. Second, that they are not, in general, equal. The latter is the way it's interpreted the overwhelming majority of the time. If you mean the former, the problem will emphasize this.

Comment: If the question is not accompanied by specific sets $A$ and $B$ then the inequality must be interpreted to mean that *in general* the two are not equal. It other words it means that there exist sets $A$ and $B$ such that $2^{A-B} \ne 2^A-2^B$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A-\emptyset)=P(A)\neq P(A)- P(\emptyset)$

Comment: I have to prove that,I know thats true.

Comment: @Noam a counterexample is all that's necessary

Comment: I dont understand your point,I have to prove that the equation is not equal,How can i prove it only by counterexample ?
Its not enought for proving that in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Take the example $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{0,1\}, B=\{1\}$. Then $A = \{0,1\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, and of course $A\notin \mathcal{P}(B)$, so $A \in \mathcal{P}(A)\setminus \mathcal{P}(B)$. However, $A\notin \mathcal{P}(A\setminus B)$ because $A\setminus B = \{0\}$.